# How to get the header frame id

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to make a transformation from my kinect to the base_link. My tf tree is build like this: base_link -> chassis -> Kinect -> front_camera.

I would be best if I can get the transformation matrix which directly transforms the data from front_camera to base_link. Because there will be other sensors in the future I want to make it as dynamic as possible. I had something like this in mind (it's like climbing the tree "backwards", from front_camera to Kinect, from Kinect to chassis, and finally from chassis to base_link):

```
//the first transformation frames     
#ifndef SOURCE_FRAME
#define SOURCE_FRAME "front_camera"
#endif
#ifndef TARGET_FRAME
#define TARGET_FRAME "Kinect"
#endif

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped ts1;
geometry_msgs::Vector3 rotation;
rotation.x = 0;
rotation.y = 0;
rotation.z = 0;
geometry_msgs::Vector3 translation;
translation.x = 0;
translation.y = 0;
translation.z = 0;

 do{
  ts1 = tBuffer.lookupTransform(TARGET_FRAME, ros::Time(0), SOURCE_FRAME, ros:Time(0), "base_link" ros::Duration(5.0));
   rotation += ts1.transform.rotation;
    
   translation += ts1.transform.translation;
   
   ts1.header.frame_id = ts1.child_frame_id;
   ts1.child_frame_id = **????????**
    
   }while(ts1.header.frame_id != "base_link");
```

I know this is probably not perfect c++ or code in general, but I hope you get what I want to do. I think I will get the syntax and everything right, but I don't know where to look for  **a function/way to get the child frame id, when I only have the header frame id?**

(If you have a different/easier approach for me, I'd be also grateful for advice)

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268275/how-to-get-the-header-frame-id/) by [kiasoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31475/kiasoso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-08**:
Is there a reason you can't just ask TF (with `lookupTransform(..)`) for the transform `front_camera->base_link` and instead want to do the work yourself? For "other sensors", just substitute *their* TF frame in place of `front_camera`.

**Comment by [kiasoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31475/kiasoso/) on 2017-08-08**:
Well as I understood the tutorials, I thought that you only can get the transform between a frame and it's parent frame and not like over a few frames! Seems like I misunderstood something! Thank you for telling me, I will try and see if I can get it rolling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is not how TF works. You can ask for the transform from any frame to any other frame, as long as there is a path between those two frames.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiasoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31475/kiasoso/) on 2017-08-09**:
I feel like a fool! Thank you so much for clearing it up!
It works fine now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-09**:
No problem, we're all learning here. Glad you got it to work.